# How to calculate integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{\frac{7}{3}} e^{\frac{-x}{2}}dx$?

Tags: integration

I have some trouble calculating the following integral:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{\frac{7}{3}} e^{\frac{-x}{2}}dx$$

I have tried all kinds of substitution and integration by parts, but things don't seem to work out.

I hope you can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fairly easy if you perform the change of variables $x/2=y$. Then the integral is

$$\begin{align}&\int_0^\infty (2y)^{7/3}e^{-y}(2\text{d}y)\\
&=2^{10/3}\int_0^\infty y^{10/3-1}e^{-y}\text{d}y\\
&=2^{10/3}\Gamma(10/3),\end{align}$$

Where $\Gamma(x)$ is the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)

Answer (score 0):

As said in comments and answers, this kind of problems involves the complete and incomplete gamma function.

For the most general case of $$I=\int x^a e^{-b x}\,dx=-b^{-a-1} \Gamma (a+1,b x)$$ $$J=\int_0^\infty x^a e^{-b x}\,dx=b^{-a-1} \Gamma (a+1)\qquad (\Re(b)>0\land \Re(a)>-1)$$